# Watir: click on drop down menu with same attributes

Tags: drop-down-menu, watir-webdriver, exact-match

```
<div class="subtab">
    <button class="ui-multiselect ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" type="button" aria-haspopup="true" style="width: 231px;">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s"></span>
            <span>None</span>
    </button>
    <button class="ui-multiselect ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" type="button" aria-haspopup="true" style="width: 231px;">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s"></span>
            <span>None</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

This is 2 drop down menu (the first one is right above the second one). They both have the exact same attribute. How do I specify which one to click on? I'm not even sure why they have the same exact attributes but they do.

Comment: Is there html missing? The html only has a div, buttons and spans. Which element are you referring to as the "drop down menu" and the "check box"?

Comment: sorry I will edit it to be more clear. The drop down menu is the button in this case.

Comment: It seems unusual that there is nothing to differentiate the two menus. While the html of the two elements is the same, usually there is something around the elements (ex a sibling) that differentiates them. How, as a user, do you differentiate which button to click?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the :index locator to specify which of the matching elements is returned. For example `:index => 0` will return the first matching element, `:index => 1` will return the second matching element, etc. Note that the :index is 0-based (ie starts at 0).

```
# To click the first one
browser.button(:class => class="ui-multiselect", :index => 0).click

# To click the second one
browser.button(:class => class="ui-multiselect", :index => 1).click
```